# How to: Assets & no results

Tags: assets

Using assets in a Matrix field, and would like to display 'no results' if a file has not been uploaded for that particular field.  Like so...

{exp:channel:entries....etc}
{matrix_field}
    {field_1}
    {field_2}

```
{if asset_field}
    {asset_field}
        {url}
    {/asset_field}
{if:else}
    No Files
{/if}
```

{/matrix_field}

I've tried various combinations of using total_results and changing where the conditional is, complex/simple.  Can't seem to find the right combination that works with both cases.  Is there a no_results tag?  What's the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just did a quick setup to test.  My matrix tag pair is test_matrix.  My Assets column is matrix_assets

```
{exp:channel:entries limit="2"}
<h1>{title}, {entry_id}</h1>
{test_matrix}
{if matrix_assets == ""}nada{/if}
{if matrix_assets != ""}stuff{/if}
{matrix_assets}
{/test_matrix}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

I did that with two entries, one with that column populated, one without.  This was the output of that template:

```
testing matrix assets - has no file, 15

nada
testing matrix assets - results, 14

stuff
```

So you can see the conditionals there are working.  Can you give that type of approach a shot?

Comment: I'm not sure what was going on earlier, but that did do it, as it should have!

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this one of two ways...

```
{matrix_field}
{if file}{file}{if:else}no results{/if}
{/matrix_field}
```

Or, if you're trying to show the "no results" if no matrix rows exist, you could do this...

```
{matrix_field}
{if total_rows == "0"}no results{/if}
{/matrix_field}
```

or this...

```
{if matrix_field == ""}no results{/if}
```

Let me know if you have questions!